# SwiftUI handle pull gesture in scrollView without loading symbol

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

I'm trying to handle a pull-up gesture in scroll view (when the user tries to scroll over the top). I have tried to use 'refreshable' but it added automatically a refresh symbol that I didn't succeed in removing.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour] and read [ask] for tips how to write a good question. You can [edit] your question with a [example] showing what you have already tried and what part is not working. This will help others answering your question.